# Elasticsearch query to match on one nested object, but return another

Tags: object, elasticsearch, nested

I have an ElasticSearch mapping as follows:

```
{
  "person": {
    "properties": {
      "accounts": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "username": {
            "type": "string"
          }
          "account_type": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to write a query that matches the username for at least one of the nested accounts, but only returns the inner hit for the account that matches a specific type.

For example, for a person with accounts

```
{"accounts": [{"username": "Foo", "type": "foo-type"},
              {"username": "Bar", "type": "bar-type"}]}}
```

I want a query that when searching for username "fo*", and type "bar-type", will return the user with an inner hit containing the nested object `{"username": "Bar", "type": "bar-type"}`, because the user has at least one account that matches the username, but the "bar-type" account type is always the one returned.

My query so far, looks like:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "nested": {
          "inner_hits": {
            "size": 1
          }
          "path": "accounts",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "query": {
                    "wildcard": {
                      "accounts.username": {
                        "value": "fo*"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but (for obvious reasons) this returns the inner hit that matches the query. I'm not sure how to amend the query to return a different nested object that matches on the type "bar-type" as specified.

Comment: Have you entered the data like this
`{"accounts": [{"username": "Foo", "type": "foo-type"},
              {"username": "Bar", "type": "bar-type"}]}}`

Comment: with your current query innerhits will return you only nested documents that match username:"fo*". For you the innerhits must have type:"bar-type"